# Count number of entries in another row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting data from one table (names). In another table I have the names of teachers.

When I'm selecting my data from the table, how can I count the total names there are for each teacher?

Example:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY limit 50");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $teacher $row['teacher'];
    $total = ?????

    echo "the name is $name and the teacher is $teacher (total number for this teacher is $total";

}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: can you post the structure of your table?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT teachersTable.*, COUNT(`names`.`id`) as NamesCount FROM `teachersTable`
LEFT JOIN `names` ON `teachersTable`.`id`=`names`.`teacherid`
GROUP BY `teachersTable`.`id`
```

Use that as your query, and the column NamesCount should be the amount of names per teacher

Comment: I would suggest counting on an indexed field, instead of * for performance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would probably be to aggregate this in the database query. Something like (if I understand you right):

```
SELECT n1.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names n2 WHERE n2.teacher = n1.teacher) AS total
FROM names n1
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 50
```

*Note that this will count the number of names in the entire table.* If you need it to count only the first 50, you will have to specify an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 50` in the subquery as well.

---

You can also loop through all your rows in PHP and count up each teacher into an associative array, then index into that to find the total. This requires fetching all your data first, then looping back through it to display. *This will count the number of names in the returned dataset, not the entire table.*